# Search issue in Jira

Tags: php, jira

I am looking for a way to search issue based on summary in Jira.

There are couple of functions to search issue, the one i need is "getIssuesFromTextSearchWithProject" but when i use it, it does not return issues just from that project but returns related issues from all projects.

Any ideas? I am doing this in PHP.

`$result = $soap->getIssuesFromTextSearchWithProject($authtoken,"PROJECT_NAME", "Search String",10);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Fault :

Project name needs to be array of projects :(

So this worked :

`$projects = array("PROJECT_NAME");`

`$result = $soap->getIssuesFromTextSearchWithProject($authtoken,$projects, "Search String",10);`